# Concatenate 2 variables (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have got a list of 20 servers : server1, server2, server3, server4, ... server20.

I need to have an array "servers" that contains these 20 servers, something like :

```
$prefix = "server"
$number = "1..20"
$servers = $prefix+number
```

My expected output  : `$servers="server1","server2","server3",...,"server20"`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to just spell it out directly:

```
$servers = 1..20 | ForEach-Object { "server$_" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to:

```
$Servers = @()
$Number | % {$servers=$servers + "$prefix$_"}
```

The first line specifies `$servers` as an array (otherwise it would be concatenated as a long string).

The second line will go through all the digits in your `$number` array and make an entry for each one.

Comment: @Joey - feel free to post an answer.  I can  get by in PS but I'm not a pro, so if you have a better method I would be excited to see it.

Comment: Maybe I just have peculiar ideas of how idiomatic PowerShell code should look. But I usually find that if you write things how you'd do it in Java or C# it looks really complicated and awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Using a format string

```
$prefix = "Server"
 1..20 | foreach {"$prefix{0}" -f $_}
```

You can also use $prefix{0:d2} if you want them to all have 2-digit (zero-filled) numbers after the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
$null, $servers = 0..20 -join ';server' -split ';'
$servers
```

Comment: That's quite a bit convoluted. Imho it's almost always better to make your intent clear – that's not what I see here.

Comment: @Joey Just showing other ways. Simplest way is to use the replace operator:
1..20 -replace '^', 'server'